# variable doesn't print correctly in echo statement

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I use functions.php file in WordPress to make image mask

**This is the code I used:**

```
function wpc_elementor_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $logo_url = the_field('site_logo_review_section');
    echo "<style>#logo-mask{
    min-height: 350px;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(" . $logo_url . ");
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-position: center center;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;}</style>";
}
add_shortcode( 'logo_mask', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode');
```

**And this is the output:**

```
http://127.0.0.1/folio/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/1038980_flower_growth_leaf_nature_petals_icon.svg
<style>#logo-mask{
        min-height: 350px;
        -webkit-mask-image: url();
        -webkit-mask-size: contain;
        -webkit-mask-position: center center;
        -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;}</style>
```

**I need** $logo_url **to print inside** -webkit-mask-image: url();

And thank you for any help

Comment: Basic rule with WordPress: Functions with a name starting with `the_` write to the output buffer directly; if you want to get the result _returned_ so that you can store it into a variable and/or insert it somewhere else, then you need to use their `get_` counterparts.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your answer, I solve this problem by using `get_field` instead of `the_field`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by using `get_field` instead of `the_field`

The reason:

> Functions with a name starting with `the_` write to the output buffer
> directly; if you want to get the result returned so that you can store
> it into a variable and/or insert it somewhere else, then you need to
> use their `get_` counterparts. [@CBroe]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).